# angular's @input vs viewchild for sending data from parent to child component

Tags: angular

I have implemented a same component more than once in one of my forms. I have to send data from parent to child components. I know that it can be achieved with @input or with viewchild. what is the performance issue of using one over the other? when should i use viewchild or input?

Comment: I hope that view child is best one instead of input.check with Behavioural subject is updated all child components .

Comment: Can anyone explain how internally in angular it makes difference in using @I/O vs viewChild. Else usecases or scenarios will be helpful to understand when its best to use what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using `@Input()`, for every change the `ngOnChanges()` will be called and causes more noise.

Using `ViewChild()` will not create any such noise. So, prefer using Viewchild over @Input()

Comment: `1 way data binding` sets the value to the object.

Comment: What do you mean by 1 way data binding sets the value to the object?

Comment: you have any prior knowledge about `angular`?

Comment: I know what is one way binding,  why do you mention that here in the comment

Comment: its answer to your first comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146989/discussion-between-kartik-and-aravind).

Comment: Why not use input setter over viewChild?

Comment: hi @Aravind  do you know answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315005/angular-using-viewchild-and-input-at-the-same-time-side-effects-or-best-practi