# Angular: Using ViewChild and Input at the Same time, Side Effects or Best practice?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Would there be any errors or collision if using `ViewChild` and `Input` at the same time? Or is it recommended practice in general?

Currently have Parent and Child component.

Requirements:

a) Parent needs to tell child component to conduct many things: mark form as touched, update values, manipulate the DOM, remove validators, etc. Things which are harder with @Input().

b) Also needs to apply input, however looking at resource here, [ViewChild vs Input/Ouput - Angular Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068954/viewchild-vs-input-ouput-angular-best-practices)

ViewChild will not display child component View data changes, from ongoing inputs with NgOnChanges(). However, using @Input() will render changes in the Input/parameter.

So if using both options, ViewChild And Input to extract both benefits, wondering if it may cause errors later? Will Native Angular 8 face any channel communication issues if it has these two ways of communicating with child?

Other Resource :

[angular's @input vs viewchild for sending data from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613057/angulars-input-vs-viewchild-for-sending-data-from-parent-to-child-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you indicate is a bit old. In my opinion, the use of viewChild is usefull when we want to use a method or function of the child(*), or change his aspect. For control a variable or a FormGroup or formControl my best bet is use @Input.

Remember that, when we pass an object to a child in a Input, there are an unique object, so parent and children has the value when any change happens -in children or in parent-, e.g. if we pass a FormGroup, you can mark as touched, remove/add validators, use setValue... from parent or form children. About @Input is true that if you has a "input fixed" -you pass a variable that not change- ,as

```
<child greet="Hello word"></child>
```

You should use [@Attribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Attribute) in constructor, NOT input

```
constructor(@Attribute('greet') greet){}
```

(*)you can use a input with a setter, but in this case I like much more use viewChild or a variable reference

Comment: if I used them together, would it cause an issue? I thought some values are not seen in NGChanges,

Comment: It should not happen any issue, but, about NgChanges, if you're using to control a Input it's better use a setter in the input https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Comment: gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question, thanks